# how to enable scrolling for specific div block in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have disabled window scroll for the page but i want to enable scroll for specific div block. Now i can able to disable and enable the scroll & mouse wheel, it is working fine. but i want to enable scroll in specific div block. please tell where i made mistake.

**The code**

```js
  var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 0, scrollLock = false;
    
        $window.scroll(function(event) {     
            if(scrollLock) {
                $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
            }
    
            previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        });
    
        $("#template").click(function() {
            scrollLock = true;
            disableScroll();
        });
        $("#close, .clear").click(function() {
            enableScroll();
            scrollLock = false;
        });
    
       // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
        // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
        var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};
    
        function preventDefault(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.preventDefault)
                e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;  
        }
    
        function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
            if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
                preventDefault(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        function disableScroll() {
            if (window.addEventListener)
                window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
            window.onwheel = preventDefault;
            window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault;
            window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault;
            document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
        }
    
        function enableScroll() {
            if (window.removeEventListener)
                window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, 
    
    false);
                window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
                window.onwheel = null; 
                window.ontouchmove = null;  
                document.onkeydown = null;  
            }
    // enabling scroll for specific div block
    
    $('.slide').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    enableScroll();
            
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Some text......</div>
    <div class="slide">I want to enable scroll for this block only</div>
```

Thanks advance

Comment: Take a look at the [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) css rule :)

Comment: in this case, overflow is not working

Comment: Add to the inner DIV `style="overflow-y:auto"`.

Comment: @jinfy why? We cant help you if you don't provide us with a reason.

Comment: the problem is mouse scrolling is not working

Comment: @jinfy that's not a reason, that's a result. We won't debug your application for you. Come back once you've found the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For only vertical scroll:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll">
```

For only horizontal scroll:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll">
```

For both:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll">
```

To hide the scroll bar:

use **hidden** value for **overflow** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using css

```
.test{
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slide{
      height: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```js
var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 0, scrollLock = false;
    
        $window.scroll(function(event) {     
            if(scrollLock) {
                $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
            }
    
            previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        });
    
        $("#template").click(function() {
            scrollLock = true;
            disableScroll();
        });
        $("#close, .clear").click(function() {
            enableScroll();
            scrollLock = false;
        });
    
       // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
        // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
        var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};
    
        function preventDefault(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.preventDefault)
                e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;  
        }
    
        function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
            if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
                preventDefault(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        function disableScroll() {
            if (window.addEventListener)
                window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
            window.onwheel = preventDefault;
            window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault;
            window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault;
            document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
        }
    
        function enableScroll() {
            if (window.removeEventListener)
                window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, 
    
    false);
                window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
                window.onwheel = null; 
                window.ontouchmove = null;  
                document.onkeydown = null;  
            }
    // enabling scroll for specific div block
    
    $('.slide').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    enableScroll();
            
    });
```

```css
.test{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide{
  height: 18px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template">Disable</div>
<div class="test">Some text......</div>
    <div class="slide">I want to enable scroll for this block only <br>I want to enable scroll for this block only<br>I want to enable scroll for this block only </div>
```

Comment: mouse scroll is not working, also i already disabled up/down arrow keys

Comment: it is working for me, i add move text and raised the height, check it now

Comment: because window is not disabled so that you can able to scroll. If you activate the disable() function, mouse scroll will not work